# Can I schedule a Twilio job to make API calls into my back-end?

Tags: callback, twilio, schedule

Is there a way to set up a Twilio scheduled job which is not making outgoing calls?  I just want it to make an API call into my own back-end service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, not today. You can investigate cloud based schedulers called out in this blog post.

[4 ways to schedule Node.js code](https://www.twilio.com/blog/4-ways-to-schedule-node-code)

Comment: To add to that: The AWS Lambda with CloudWatch approach is much easier to set up with the [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) than with AWS directly, the docs are [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/).